# Examining Multiple Ports When Running NetCat (nc)

Tags: linux, redhat, port, netcat

I am looking to test if specific ports are on a host are open. I am using:

```
nc -z host 22
nc -z host 80
nc -z host 443
nc -z host 8080
```

which works, but it would be nice to use a one-liner like:

```
nc -z host 22 80 443 8080
```

which doesn't work.

I would like to avoid the port range `nc -z host 22-8080` as noted in the man page, if possible, as there is a large gap in port #s I am looking to check. Also, I don't want to scan every port and be seen as scanning for open ports.

Short of writing a bash loop, what are my options for testing if the ports are open? I have dozens of hosts each with a handful of ports to check.

Comment: why aren't you using [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/)?

Comment: @MikePennington: nmap is not installed and I don't have access to install it.

Comment: FYI, you need to use `nc -zv hostname port`; if you do this without `-v`, then you won't get feedback on whether the port is open or closed (at least for my version of `nc` on Debian Squeeze)

Comment: @MikePennington: My version on redhat is fine with `-z` (so far). So, nmap it is, eh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `-w 1` below to limit timeouts to 1 second.  I also use `-v` for the reasons mentioned in comments.  I used `-n` to refuse delays for reverse DNS lookups...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ for i in $(echo "172.16.1.1,172.16.1.5"|tr "," "\n"); do echo -e "22\n80\n443\n8080" | xargs -i nc -w 1 -zvn $i {}; done
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.1] 22 (ssh) open
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.1] 80 (www) : Connection timed out
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.1] 443 (https) open
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.1] 8080 (http-alt) : Connection timed out
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.5] 22 (ssh) open
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.5] 80 (www) open
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.5] 443 (https) open
(UNKNOWN) [172.16.1.5] 8080 (http-alt) : Connection refused
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

Comment: macOS always think different. So for Catalina users, use `for i in $(echo "192.168.1.1"|tr "," "\n"); do echo -e "22\n80\n443\3389\n8080" | xargs -L 1 nc -G 1 -zvn $i; done`.

Answer (score 5):

If you like [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) as much as I do, try this:

```
parallel nc -vz host ::: 22 80 443 8080
```

*Sample Output:*

```
Connection to foo.example.com 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
nc: connect to foo.example.com port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to foo.example.com port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to foo.example.com port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

This method is also faster in some cases since it's testing connecting to ports in parallel, not serial.  Specifically this would be where the remote host (or intervening firewall) discards your packets to stay stealth (as opposed to a successful connection or forceful reject).

**Tip:** in most Linux distros, you can install `parallel` from your package manager.

**Update:** With `parallel`, this generalizes super well to cover an often needed case of multiple hosts x multiple ports. The following example uses `parallel` to iterate over the cross product, so you don't need to write any nested loops.

```
parallel nc -vz ::: host1 host2 host3 ::: 22 80 443 8080
```

*Output:*

```
Connection to host1 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
Connection to host1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
Connection to host1 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
nc: connect to host1 port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to host2 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
nc: connect to host2 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to host2 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to host2 port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to host3 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
nc: connect to host3 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to host3 port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to host3 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Just as the previous example, `parallel` executes the connection tests in parallel.  Note, the default parallelism is how many threads your system have, but can override easily with the `-j` switch to any value. You could easily get away with `parallel -j 50 ...` or even higher since testing sockets is not a CPU intensive task.

Answer (score 1):

Netcat is not really a scanner, as the comment suggests nmap would be a better option here. Not using the the port range option I guess you are left with wrapping it in a shell script;

```
    for host in $(cat hostlist); do
        for port in $ports; do nc -z $host $port; done
    done
```

etc..

Answer (score 1):

On Gentoo Linux (with net-analyzer/netcat-110-r9 installed):

```
$ nc -vz www.example.com 80 443
www.example.com [93.184.216.34] 80 (http) open

$ nc -vvz www.example.com 80 443
www.example.com [93.184.216.34] 80 (http) open
www.example.com [93.184.216.34] 443 (https) : Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

In Redhat 6 you could run something like this as a true one-liner:

```
nc -znv -w 2 <host> <port1>; nc -znv -w 2 <host> <port2>
```

-z tests port
-n doesn't resolve DNS
-v give verbose output
-w timeout after 2 seconds
; strings one command after another as long as you don't mind typing it out again.

I like the suggestions for using a loop if you are scanning multiple ports, however if it's 2 or 3 and you are already trying to loop through a list with something like SSH, stringing commands like this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ HOST="10.116.XX.YYY"; PORTs="80 6080 443";for port in $(echo $PORTs); do nc -vz $HOST $port; done
nc: connect to 10.116.XX.YYY port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to 10.116.XX.YYY 6080 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.116.XX.YYY 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```